# how can i made same output file in nohup shell script code?

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell, nohup

Now, I'm running on server.

Log management is performed with *nohup*,
the result is output in 5 units.

*nohup* shell script code is like this.

```
nohup python main.py &
nohup python main.py &
nohup python main.py &
nohup python main.py &
nohup python main.py &
```

the outputs came out in units of five.

like this >>> [IMAGE](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpSQd.png)

I want the log files made of the shell script code above to be printed in order, not just the fifth.

How can I do?

Comment: Please [don’t post images of code or error messages.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try piping your output into sort like:

```
nohup python main.py | sort &
```

But I am not sure why you are running the same python script 5 times. I believe nohup outputs to a log file in the directory where the command is run, if anything, try `cat nohup.out | sort`

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: thanks! i will try later :)

The reason it works 5 times is because the server has 5 CPUs.